PostgreSQL how to merge rows where some fields match and others are null
I have some data that looks like the below:



id
category
sub_category
sub_sub_category




1
Category 1
null
null


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
null


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 1


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 2


1
Category 2
Subcategory 2
SubSubCategory 2



I need it to look like this:



id
category
sub_category
sub_sub_category




1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 1


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 2


1
Category 2
Subcategory 2
SubSubCategory 2



Is this kind of filtering possible in postgresql?
I've seen some answers suggesting to use group by to aggregate rows together but I don't think that would work in this case, because I only want to combine rows where the categories and/or subcategories match. If I used group by category, sub_category then the result would be like the below, right?



id
category
sub_category
sub_sub_category




1
Category 1
null
null


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 1


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 2


1
Category 2
Subcategory 2
SubSubCategory 2




Would this work in your data... select id, category, max(sub_cat), max(sub_sub_cat) from table group by id, category? It works for the current sample data, but would not work if you have another row such as (ID 1, cat 1, subcat 1, subsubcat 2).

Match what? This Subcategory 1 , null  is  as much of a  match as Subcategory 1  SubSubCategory 1. What are you looking to match to?

@Isolated I think that would probably not work, since it's very likely to have another row like (ID1, cat 1, subcat 1, subcat 2)

@AdrianKlaver what I want is an output like what is indicated, where the rows are collapsed if the actual data that is there matches, ignoring the nulls

In that case, I would add that sample row to your sample data above, as well as update your desired output.

You still have not said what match you are looking for? Though I'm guessing that what you want is all columns to be not null.

Assuming that null values are only the last in the row:
(<value>,null,null,null) or  (<value>,<value>,null,null)
and NOT (<value>,null,<value>,<value>)
See example



id
category
sub_category
sub_sub_category




1
Category 1
null
null


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
null


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 1


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 2


1
Category 2
Subcategory 2
SubSubCategory 2



select distinct id,category,sub_category,sub_sub_category
from(
  select id,category,sub_category
    ,coalesce(sub_sub_category
            ,first_value(sub_sub_category)over(partition by id,category,sub_category order by sub_sub_category)
        )sub_sub_category
  from(
    select  id,category
      ,coalesce(sub_category
          ,first_value(sub_category)over(partition by id,category order by sub_category)
       )sub_category
      ,sub_sub_category
    from(
      select id
         ,coalesce(category
              ,first_value(category)over(partition by id order by category)
           ) category
         ,sub_category,sub_sub_category
     from test
    )a
  )b
)c
order by id,category,sub_category,sub_sub_category




id
category
sub_category
sub_sub_category




1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 1


1
Category 1
Subcategory 1
SubSubCategory 2


1
Category 2
Subcategory 2
SubSubCategory 2



fiddle
More strict query
select  id,category,sub_category,sub_sub_category -- all, not distinct
from(
  select id,category,sub_category
    ,coalesce(sub_sub_category
            ,first_value(sub_sub_category)over(partition by id,category,sub_category order by sub_sub_category)
        )sub_sub_category
  from(
    select  id,category
      ,coalesce(sub_category
          ,first_value(sub_category)over(partition by id,category,sub_sub_category order by sub_category)
       )sub_category
      ,sub_sub_category
    from(
      select id
         ,coalesce(category
              ,first_value(category)over(partition by id,sub_category,sub_sub_category order by category)
           ) category
         ,sub_category,sub_sub_category
     from test
    )a
  )b
)c
order by id,category,sub_category,sub_sub_category


Ahh, that did it, thank you so much!
